# Mouse scroll on nav scrolling page instead

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, webkit

We have a `Twitter Bootstrap` site that uses a dropdown menu with a height of `500px`. It seems that in `WebKit` browsers scrolling with a mouse scroll wheel does not scroll the menu when the mouse is over it, but rather the page. Using Firefox, it performs better, but sometimes scrolls the page when your mouse is over the menu.

**Test by viewing the "General Policies" menu item:**

http://www.puc.edu/campus-services/student-services/student-handbook

[image]

**Is there a way to give the menu focus, when your mouse is over it, so that the mouse scroll wheel can scroll the menu rather than the content of the page?**

Answer (score 0):

adding

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

to `.dropdown-menu` allows me to use a scroll wheel on Chrome (webkit browser)

Comment: Hmm, I did this but it gives some really strange behavior. Sometimes the menu isn't there, and I have to move my mouse to make parts of it appear. And also, it DOES sometimes scroll the menu, but sometimes not. Tested in Safari, but Chrome also doesn't always allow scroll in the nav.

Answer (score 0):

You can give overflow-y: auto that will work. But this happening because of z-index value. Change the z-index value of:

```
nav .dropdown-menu {
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

And it will work.